# Update ListBox Items when there are changes in property of element in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, observablecollection

I am a newbie with windows phone development. I have a class named 'State'. It keeps the name and capital of the state. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.

```
public class State:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private string _capital;
    public State() { }
    public State(string name, string capital)
    {
        this.Name=name;
        this.Capital=capital;
    }
    public string Name
    {   get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        { 
            _name=value;
            OnPropertyChanged(this,"Name");
            OnPropertyChanged(this, "Name");
        }
    }
    public string Capital
    {
        get
        {
            return _capital;
        }
        set
        {
            _capital = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(this, "Capital");
            OnPropertyChanged(this, "Name");
        }    
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (Name + " " + Capital );
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  
    public void OnPropertyChanged(object sender,string Property)  
    {  
        if (PropertyChanged != null)  
        {  
            PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));  
        }  
    }  
}
```

The ObservableCollection maintains my list of states. I want to update the changes in one property of one element of the Collection and reflect the changes in ListBox. However the changes are not reflected. Here is my MainPage class. I change the property value on button click event.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<State> MyStatelist;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyStatelist = new ObservableCollection<State>();
        MyStatelist.Add(new State("State1","Capital1"));
        States.ItemsSource = MyStatelist;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyStatelist[0].Name = "Abcd";
        t1.Text = MyStatelist[0].Name;
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML code

```
<ListBox x:Name="States" Margin="0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyStatelist Mode=TwoWay}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"  >
    </ListBox>
```

Is there anyway i can notify the listbox that it has to update.

Thanks A Lot!!

Comment: From what I can see, this should work

Answer (score 0):

You bind `ObservableCollection<State>` twice. First, you create new object in `MainPage` constructor. And this is enough. When you do it in XAML `ItemsSource="{Binding MyStatelist Mode=TwoWay}"`, new instance of `ObservableCollection<State>` is created. That's why `MyStatelist[0].Name = "Abcd"` doesn't work because `MyStatelist` is not set as the source of items anymore. Just remove the binding in XAML.

One more thing. You have to add `ItemTemplate` to your `ListBox` and correctly bind properties of `State` class. Here's my example that works:

```
<ListBox x:Name="States" Margin="0,10" 
         Grid.Row="1"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
         Background="White" 
         Foreground="Black" 
         Height="Auto" 
         Width="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0, 0, 12, 0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Capital}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas Rejman. That really worked well. And the explaination was good. But i didnt get one thing, why is there necessity to define itemtemplate. Doesnt the Listbox.ItemSource work?

Comment: ItemSource defines WHAT to show. ItemTemplate defines HOW. So ItemTemplate allows you to customize. Default ItemTemplate is a TextBlock which doesn't take your class parameters but just do ToString() once and display it. By defining your own template you can change it.

Comment: In order to make the UI subscribe to the propertychanged event you have to bind to the properties.

Comment: Thank you Florian and Lukasz. That worked really well. However my actual question is this

As mentioned by Lukasz taht two instances of the observablecollection are created. Which one of them is bound to the listbox first? 
In MainPage class i have declared MyStatelist object and it has single element. How come the same data is seen in the instance created by XAML file when i write  ' ItemsSource="{Binding MyStatelist Mode=TwoWay}" '

Comment: You know, I just guessed that you have declared MyStatelist in MainPage.xaml resources. That makes it create. But if you didn't, I think it shouldn't be possible to use MyStatelist in XAML if it's only declared in code behind as you did.

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding to the properties yet. Use this instead:

```
<ListBox x:Name="States" Margin="0,10" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"  >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                            <Binding Path="Capital" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```